# Import Excel into MySql - An external table is not in the expected format

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, excel-2007

I'm trying to import .xlsx file(MS Excel 2007) into database(My SQL).
It's working in my local PC but not in a server PC where the application is run under IIS6

This is the error message thrown from Try-Catch clause

```
 An external table is not in the expected format.
```

I've installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable 
and 2007 Office System Driver in the server PC.

Here is the code

```
    private void vIPToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fiDatabase = null;
        ofdDatabase.Title = "Select VIP list to input";
        ofdDatabase.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx";
        if (ofdDatabase.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fiDatabase = new FileInfo(ofdDatabase.FileName);
            if (fiDatabase.Exists)
            {
                DeleteVIPList();

                lblDateCreated.Text = fiDatabase.CreationTime.ToShortDateString();
                lblDatabase.Text = fiDatabase.Name;
                lblLocation.Text = fiDatabase.DirectoryName;
                lblSize.Text = String.Format("{0:0,0.0}", fiDatabase.Length) + " byte";
                btnLoadDatabase.Visible = true;
                file = new StreamReader(fiDatabase.FullName);

                OleDbConnection theConnection =
                    new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\\VIPLIST092211.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";");
                try
                {
                    theConnection.Open();
                    OleDbDataAdapter theDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", theConnection);
                    DataSet theDS = new DataSet();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    theDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                    theConnection.Close();

                    dgvCustomer.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

                    lblRecord.Text = dgvCustomer.Rows.Count.ToString();

                    update = new Update();
                    update.connectionString = MyCon;
                    update.UpdateVIPList(dt);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Database Selected");
            }
        }
    }
```

I got and the error message at "theConnection.Open()"
Please share with me the solution if anyone's had this problem before.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your UpdateVIPList Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Suggestion..

to upload bulk data into mysql from excel you can use csv format which is more convenient and not require any drivers to install in server pc.Here is the steps

1)Save your excel in csv format using save as option

2)order the
    column according to the table format

3)Run the following query

load
    data local infile 'E:\FileName.csv' into table templates fields
    terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n'
    (col1,col2,col3,col4)

**But it's depend on your usecase**

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your UpdateVIPList Method?

Im not sure, but Maybe you need to loop on your DataTable to insert each rows on your table

Example:

```
      foreach(DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
       {   
                string mycolumnName = drow["ColumName"].ToString();   
                // Loop Per Row then Update
                update = new Update();
                update.UpdateVIPList(mycolumnNam);
       }
```

where

```
public bool UpdateVIPList(string mycolumnname)
     {

       //Your insert Logic Insert into Table (..) values (...)
       //Do stuff
        return true;
     }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You said that it was working only on localhost. The problem might in your connection string, you specified 'Data Source=c:\VIPLIST092211.xlsx' as exact path on current host. But this file has to be accessible from server host too. You should share this file for your clients.